Error Loading Hugging Face Model Locally: 'FloatProgress' Object has No Attribute 'Style'
I’m encountering an issue when trying to load Hugging Face models locally using the transformers library. The code below:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B") 
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B")

results in the following error:
tokenizer_config.json

Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed or enabled properly. Reconnecting the current kernel may help.


AttributeError: 'FloatProgress' object has no attribute 'style'

This issue arises during the download of tokenizer configuration files and seems to be related to the tqdm progress bar used in the Hugging Face library.
Interestingly, this same model and code run perfectly on Google Colab without any issues, which suggests that the problem might be specific to my local setup.
Steps Taken:

Checked Environment: The issue persists across different models, not just the one mentioned.

Library Versions: I have the latest versions of transformers, huggingface_hub, and tqdm installed.

Reinstalled Libraries: Reinstalled tqdm and huggingface_hub but the issue remains.


I am not sure why this is happening. Because , same code works with colab but why it is not working with local machine I don't know. I tried multiple ways like using huggingface_hub, git of that model. But in every way, I found this error.
How to handle this error?
